# How to display all prime numbers that exist in the given limits

Tags: javascript

Create a HTML page which accepts user input into the text field as integer between 10 and
120. When the user pressed the “Display” button, your function created in JavaScript should
able to display all prime integer between 1 and 120.

**Example**

Input Integer:
20

The Function should return:
`1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19`

```
function primeNumbers(){
var p;
var n = document.primeForm.primeText.value;
var d;
var x;
var prime;
var displayAll = 2 + " ";
for(p = 3; p <= n; p = p+2){
    x = Math.sqrt(p);
    prime=1;
    for(d = 3; prime && (d <= x); d = d+2)
    if((p%d) == 0)
        prime = 0;
    else
        prime = 1;
    if(prime == 1){ 
        displayAll = displayAll + p + " ";
    }
}
document.primeForm.primeArea.value = displayAll;
```

}​

but it can display more than 120 :(

Comment: Please use the homework tag for homework.  You will still get an answer, but it will be oriented toward helping you learn.

Comment: if this is homework can you please tag it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop is where everything is happening. So if the value is outside of the range that you want, then don't allow the `for` loop to execute. In order to do this, place an `if` statement around the `for` loop.

Since you only plan to use these numbers once, it doesn't matter if you enter in the min/max directly in the `if` statement or if you make a variable to hold the value. Most people suggest keeping all of your variables at the top in case you ever need to change the range: it's easier to find them.

On to the `if` statement: `n` is the deciding factor in whether or not to execute the `for` loop. Here is the statement: `if (n >= 10 && n <= 120) { insert the for loop here }`. All you're doing is checking if the input is greater than or equal to 10 AND checking that the input is less than or equal to 120.

Note: if you don't want anything displaying, then include the line right after the `for` loop that is outputting the results in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

While Rhyono's suggestion will work, in that nothing will happen unless `n` is between 10 and 120, remember that this is on an interactive page, so giving the user appropriate feedback is **very important**.

When people click a button on a web page, they expect something to happen. For this reason I would suggest you take a different approach here, something like this:

```
function displayClicked()
{
    var n = document.primeForm.primeText.value;

    if (n < 10 || n > 120)
    {
        // Display an appropriate error to the user like:
        // "n must be between 10 and 120."
    }
    else
    {
        primeNumbers(n);
    }
}
```

Using this approach, the user recevies useful feedback when they type in an invalid number, instead of nothing happening.